Refresh User's Session With Banno Plugin Framework
Has anyone refreshed a user's session from Banno's plugin framework widget? We want to use a card to update preferences and then have Banno reload the page so that the preferences are available throughout the session.
I think I just need to do an ajax call, but do not know which one to use.

It sounds like you're not asking about literal sessions (in the API sense), but perhaps instead asking something like 'how do I get the user's Dashboard to reload?'

We don't have a method to cause the Dashboard to be refreshed. For folks using the Plugin Bridge to handle navigating from the Card Face to the Expanded View, some folks have noticed that there are Alpha events that seem tantalizingly close, but don't actually refresh the Dashboard per se.
